# How to get TOP 10 in MySQL with combined data rows?

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a challenge I can't seem to handle.

```
+------+--------+-----------+-------+
|  id  |  user  |  genres   | books |
+------+--------+-----------+-------+
|  1   |  John  |  crimes   |   2   |
|  2   |  John  |  scienc   |   1   |
|  3   |  John  |  nature   |   4   |
|  4   |  Pete  |  nature   |   3   |
|  5   |  Pete  |  crime    |   2   |
|  6   |  Mary  | nature    |   20  |
+------+--------+-----------+-------+
```

I would like to have a SQL query that gets the total amount of books the users own, no matter the genre and would like to ORDER them by who has the most.

In this example, you see that Mary has 20 books, Pete 5 and John has 7 so my desired result would be an array like:

```
result[0][user] = "Mary";
result[0][total] = 20;
result[1][user] = "John";
result[1][total] = 7;
result[2][user] = "Pete";
result[2][total] = 5;
```

How can I get this into one SQL? Should I use CONCAT or TOP or something? I use MySQL & PHP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need GROUP BY with SUM

```
SELECT `user`, SUM(books) AS total_books
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `user`
ORDER BY total_books DESC
```

If you only want the first 10 then you can use

```
SELECT `user`, SUM(books) AS total_books
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `user`
ORDER BY total_books DESC LIMIT 10`
```

By the way, you might want to rethink your schema slightly. Duplicating info is against the principles of normalisation. You might want to add a new `owners` table:

```
  +-----------+-------------+
  | owner_id  |  owner_name |
  +-----------+-------------+
  |     1     |    John     |
  |     2     |    Pete     |
  |     3     |    Mary     |
  +-----------+-------------+
```

and then reference this by `owner_id` in your `books` table.

Comment: If I use GROUP BY, am I not skipping rows? Will they all be included in the SUM()?
About your point regarding normalisation... You're right but I use a example here to get it simple :-)

Comment: @glooh that's the point of GROUP BY. It will sum all rows for each user.

Answer (score 2):

```
select user, sum(books) as total
from your_table
group by user
order by sum(books)
limit 10
```

Comment: You write ORDER BY SUM(books) but liquorvicar writes ORDER BY total_books as he stated total_books earlier, like your 'total'. What would be better to use?

Comment: I recommend using liquorvicar's method.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT sum(books) as book_count, user  FROM `books` GROUP BY (user) order by book_count DESC
```